# Move one element of an 2d array to an empty index using java

Tags: java, arrays, 2d

I am attempting to move an element in a 2d array from its current position to a spot that is equal to ' '.

```
for (int r = 0 ; r < tissue.length ; r++ ){
            for (int s = 0 ; s < tissue[i].length ; s++ ){
                if ((isSatisfied(tissue, row , column , threshold) == false){
                    int totalMoves = 0;
                    totalMoves++;
                    for (int t = 0 ; t < tissue.length ; t++ ){
                        for (int u = 0 ; u < tissue[i].length ; u++ ){
                            if ([t][u] == ' '){
                                [r][s] = [t][u];
                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: And the problem would be...

Comment: i do not know if this is actually moving the value from [r][s] to [t][u].

Comment: Print the array to the screen and see.

Comment: I cannot currently compile. Is this an effective way?

Comment: I have no idea. If you can't compile/test it, how can I?

Answer (score 0):

You don't actually ask a question, but I'm guessing that the reason for this post is that the code you posted is not working as intended. After a quick read, I see a couple of problems.

- You have two suspicious lines where you are using `tissue[i].length`. The variable `i` is not defined anywhere in your posted code, so I assume that it's defined elsewhere (or else the code doesn't compile). It looks, however, like the first should be `tissue[r].length` and the second should be `tissue[t].length`.
- When you do find a position containing a `' '`, you copy over the value but you then continue looping. From the title of the question, my guess is that you should be breaking out of the loop(s) (or returning from the method) at that point to prevent further assignment to all `' '` positions.